# how to fix apt-update error: Package Hash sum mismatch

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, updates, cuda

after installing nvidia cuda 9.0, I realize that tensorflow doesn't support it at this moment. I tried to remove cuda9.0 and install cuda8.0 back. but I got the error below when I do **'apt-get update'**

```
Err:28 http://113.215.21.30:80/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 66.8 kB in 15s (4,190 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://113.215.21.30:80/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It looks like there is some mistake with the dpkg index files,
I'm wondering how I can remove this entry below from the apt-get update list, so I can update ?

```
http://113.215.21.30:80/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove PPA from your source list and re-add it if needed (or add another one if it's different)

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

or using GUI (Software & Updates -> Other Software)
[image: Software & Updates on XUbuntu 16.04]